# Disable a group of radio buttons by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable all of the radio buttons in the same class when another is checked. This function works with checkboxes, but not when I use radio buttons.  Any help would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/neilcosby123/qssvzap4/1/

```
function radcheck(){
var ra = document.getElementById("main")
if(ra.checked){
    $(".radioclass").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".radioclass").attr("checked", false);
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just hide the radio buttons instead of trying to disable them?

Comment: I also have to enable them when another is selected, so I don't want them to be hidden.

Comment: FYI - Your JSFiddle does not reference JQuery, so things will fail.

Comment: Are all these radio buttons in the same group (i.e. do they have the same name)? If they do, there is no need to see the checked attribute to false and you would then just need to select the radio buttons by name and disable them.

Comment: But your enable button can just show them again. It's very easy: https://jsfiddle.net/qssvzap4/6/

Comment: @Cruiser this is not disable this is show and hide.

Comment: I know. show and hide is, imho, a better way to do it and it accomplishes the same functionality. unless he wants to go through later and look for all enabled/disabled radio buttons, i think show/hide is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to write without any context (like why do you want to do this?).

I assume that what you need is this:

```
$("#main").change(function() {
  var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

  $(".radioclass")
    .prop("disabled", isChecked)
    .prop("checked", !isChecked);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qssvzap4/9/

Comment: It's a form with a list of medication options in different categories. A radio to select the category, then medications in that category need to be selected. The problem is users keep selecting one category, and medications in a different one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var $radios = $('.radioclass');

    $('#main').on('click', function(){
        $radios.prop('disabled', this.checked).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qssvzap/7/

Comment: This is good but there should be a toggle so it can get enabled cuz if you want to enable so you can press buttons again you have to refresh page.

Comment: Changed it to a checkbox and made it re-enable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with vanilla js, since the jquery isn't really critical, and honestly, I feel like it is overkill for this situation.

```
function radcheck(){
    var ra = document.getElementById("main");
    if(ra.checked){
        var radios = document.querySelectorAll('.radioclass');
        for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
           radios[i].checked = false;
           radios[i].disabled = true;
         }
    }
}
```

If you want them to toggle, you could do the same loop but instead do:

```
   radios[i].checked = !radios[i].checked;
   radios[i].disabled = !radios[i].disabled;
```

Answer (score -2):

actually in ur given fiddle. you have not linked the jquery library.
check the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/e9zeL6eL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main').click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(".radioclass").each(function () {
                $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
                //$(".radioclass").attr("checked", false);
            });
        }
    })
});
```